# What are signed cookies and why are they useful?

Tags: django, security, cookies

In some presentation from EuroPython "signed cookies" have been mentioned. Since googling didn't help -- I haven't found anything besides "yes, they are cool, this is how you do it", most in context of Django -- maybe someone on StackOverflow has a good explanation for me.

So, what are signed cookies, why would I want to use them, how are the downsides?

Comment: Perhaps answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240246/signed-session-cookies-a-good-idea

Answer (score 3):

A signed cookies provides a mechanism where you can trust the data in a cookie from a client.

The upsides are that you wouldn't necessarily have to store any session information on your server.

The downside is that you should keep the cookie data to a minimum.

Comment: Another downside is that they are often implemented incorrectly.